# guard reads nil but var is equal to something

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I have a global var

```
var race: String?
```

7 buttons in a vertical scroll view tagged 0-6 inside of an embedded view controller in my main view controller.  All of the buttons are linked to one IBAction.

```
    @IBAction func raceBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        race = "American Indian"
    case 1:
        race = "Asian"
    case 2:
        race = "Black or African American"
    case 3:
        race = "Hispanic or Latino"
    case 4:
        race = "Pacific Islander"
    case 5:
        race = "White"
    default:
        race = "Other"
    }
}
```

Another button that checks you have made a selection and submits it

```
@IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let race = race where race != "" else {
        return
    }
    print("yes")
}
```

This will not step through when I make a selection. I have the main view controller and the embedded one using the same view controller file.
I'm using swift 2.2 xCode 7.3.1.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure the `raceBtn` method is being called? Can you add a `print(race)` at the beginning and end of that method?

Comment: Maybe do a debugPrint before your return, after the guard.

Comment: What's the value of "race" when you are pressing submit?

Comment: @nathan yes I can and it does.

Comment: @Shades the value depends on what button you hit in the scroll view.  none of them are returning a value when you hit submit, but if I ad a print line in their button' fun it does.

Answer (score 0):

In a playground, the line `guard let race = race where race != "" else {return}` yields an error message of

> Definition conflicts with previous value

Change the line to:

```
guard let selected = race where race != "" else { return }
```

where the new variable has any name other than "race"

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was showing nil because I need to pass the value from one view controller to the other.